# Can SteerMouse sensitivity be automated?

Tags: applescript, mouse, automation

I have to adjust the cursor sensitivity in SteerMouse every time I switch between my home mouse and my work mouse. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if SteerMouse supports applescript by opening applescript editor and then clicking File -> Open Dictionary. If it does, please reply back.

In the meantime, there is a indirect solution, which is to have two separate preferences files for work and home and switching between them.

First, set your home settings. You'll find the preferences file at ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse.prefs. Copy that and rename the copy to SteerMouse_home.prefs. Then adjust them for work and copy those preferences and name them SteerMouse_work.prefs.

Then, in applescript editor, copy this code and save it as an application.

```
property myLocation : ""

if myLocation is "" then
    set myLocation to "Home"
end if

if myLocation is "Home" then
    do shell script "mv -f ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse_home.prefs ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse.prefs"
    set myLocation to "Work"

else if myLocation is "Work" then
    do shell script "mv -f ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse_work.prefs ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse.prefs"
    set myLocation to "Home"
end if

#You'll only need this part if the app needs to be restarted for the changes to occur.
tell application "SteerMouse"
    quit
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: In short, move the prefs file and restart the app. Obviously! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

While @frediemathews answered the question, I wanted to post the code I ended up using.

SteerMouse saves its preferences instantly, so I adjusted the settings three times and copied the preference file each time. I have three AppleScripts which contain code like this:

```
tell application "SteerMouse Manager" to quit

do shell script "cp ~/Misc/steermouse-prefs/fast ~/Library/Preferences/SteerMouse.prefs"

tell application "SteerMouse Manager" to activate
```

(SteerMouse Manager is an application which is hidden inside SteerMouse.app)